# Create Audiobooks from PDFs or text with no limit on characters

Tags: audiobook

I have roughly 80 PDF documents that range from 2 pages to 20 pages each. I am trying to find a way to convert them each to an audiobook to help me read and study the documents, including listening to while out. I believe I am able to convert them to text if that makes things easier. I am trying to find an app or program or some solution where the voice is more human than robotic and where there is no word/character limit. I have come across some apps that have pretty good natural voices that can read the text but the ones I have seen have limits on how many words/characters. I am looking to play this audio through my iPhone and also on my PC (Lenovo). Please let me know if you need anything clarified regarding what I am looking for. I appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: Can you specify on what operating system do you need it and what price (if any) are you willing to pay?

Comment: I have a Lenovo laptop with Windows 10 as the operating system. If I can create on that and use it there or on my iPhone that would be great. Or I could just create on my iPhone if that was the only option. I am willing to pay if there was a cost to use a program or application, I am flexible and open on the price depending on functionality. Everything I found with priced tiers had limits on characters and I think I would exceed those limits